# How do you do a update if you don't know the id, and just you know a information with another table relationed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to do this query:

```
UPDATE asignaturasemestre 
   SET asignatura11 = 'cambiado' 
 WHERE asignaturasemestre.iddatosgenerales = datosgenerales.iddatosgenerales 
   AND datosgenerales.curp = 'CURP'
```

I know this is bad, but this is the idea:

As you can see, I don't know the `iddatosgenerales`, but I do know it has a foreign key (`iddatosgenerales`). The users will write the curp only, so with that curp is not in the another table, so I need to update the another table but I don't know the id of this row.
As I have told you, I just know the `CURP` column, but this is in the another table (this is unique).  But it is not the primary key - it doesn't mind, the id is `iddatosgenerales` which is a foreign key in the another table where I want to update.

Comment: Why do you downvote our answers when you're using mssql server instead of mysql? edit. I haven't seen OMG Ponies' comment that wrote you the same thing.

Comment: If you don't even know what rdbms you're using it's not our fault.

Comment: @nick: Next time someone asks, I'll answer: ***"I'm using My-SQL-Server"***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for **MySQL**:

```
UPDATE asignaturasemestre AS a
     , datosgenerales AS d
SET  a.asignatura11='cambiado' 
WHERE a.iddatosgenerales=d.iddatosgenerales 
  AND d.curp='CURP'
```

And this for **SQL-Server**:

```
UPDATE a
SET  a.asignatura11='cambiado' 
FROM asignaturasemestre AS a
    JOIN datosgenerales AS d
        ON a.iddatosgenerales=d.iddatosgenerales 
WHERE d.curp='CURP'
```

Comment: see this bug Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. with that code, and i know you can put ( , ) in a update sintaxis

Comment: @angel: That error message is not the format you'd get from MySQL, but SQL Server...  It makes a difference, knowing what database you're using because they don't all support the exact same thing.

Comment: thnx @OMG, I was starting to wonder which version of MySQL does not support this syntax on UPDATE...

Answer (score 0):

```
update asignaturasemestre,datosgenerales 
set asignatura11='cambiado' 
where asignaturasemestre.iddatosgenerales=datosgenerales.iddatosgenerales 
and datosgenerales.curp='CURP'
```

Comment: you can't put asignaturasemestre, datosgenerales, you cant use ( , )

Answer (score 0):

Now i have found the answer it is

```
update asignaturasemestre set asignatura11='cambiado' 
where iddatosgenerales=(select datosgenerales.iddatosgenerales from datosgenerales inner join asignaturasemestre on
datosgenerales.iddatosgenerales=asignaturasemestre.iddatosgenerales where curp='123ABC');
```

I did the query normal, but when i put the iddatosgenerales i do a query getting the iddatosgenerales with curp user gave me